# Error in Importing gcp BigQuery Data into the Power BI Service

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, powerbi, dashboard

I'm trying to connect a GCP table to Power BI  but its getting failed with the below error :

```
Failed to save changes to server. Error returned : « Erreur OLE DB ou ODBC: [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Response too large to return. Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration. For more details, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors.
Erreur OLE DB ou ODBC: Exception de HRESULT : 0x80040E4E.
```

Any clues?
Thanks

Comment: Which ODBC Driver are you using and are you set to use Legacy or Standard SQL?

Comment: And if you're not using the built-in BigQuery connector, why not? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery